# postpone transitions with fragments

Tags: android, fragment, transition, android-glide

I'm using shared element transition of fragments to move from a grid list of images (with Recyclerview) to the image item in a ViewPager and I use Glide to load images. but with my implementation there are problems I cannot find anywhere solutions for them. The most annoying one is that view is lagging when glide tries to load images.

Some suggest to postpone transition using postponeStartTransition(). But this method is not working when setReorderingAllowed() is false. and when setReorderingAllowed() is true the fragment transitions are not working. how should I solve this problem?